# How to reset display settings

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, dell-inspiron, default-settings

I have connected an external monitor to my Dell N7520 notebook, than been playing with the setting a little on ***Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution***

I don't really know what i have done over there, but i accidentally have applied a setting that make the external monitor to show nothing, a black screen basically... trying to fix it, i accidentally applied an other setting that shut down my main laptopn monitor when i connect an external one :\?

to clear it all out, when i connect an external monitor, the main one show black screen and the external one is not functioning at all.. like its blocked?

how can i reset those settings to default?

Comment: what happens when you press Fn+F1 (or just F1)?

Comment: @Chin it basically did nothing but, dear god you're awesome! seeing what F1 is doin, when screen when black i have dashed with the keyboard pointers to the third option and hit enter, it fixed it! thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to press `Fn + F1` (or just `F1`) a few times to toggle between display modes.